# Независимые сбилдженные модули/компоненты Vue 3

Tags: vue.js

Есть такая задача. Нужно в моем хтмл файлы подключать или отключать сбилдженные заранее модули Vue3. Таким образом чтобы при отключении модуля ничего не ломалось, просто отсутсвовали какой то функционал и страницы. Каким модули включены решает Java на сервере. Также нужно передавать роутинг в приложения например(сам роутинг будет например делать java). Как сделать несколько модулей я вроде как понял, но как всё это правильно настроить и подключать непонятно.